# jQuery: Get detail of image loading error

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, http

I have a javascript that calls a server-side script (PHP) that serves up requested images. There are parameters passed in for the **user** and **image key**.

If the requested image does not exist I respond with a 404 error. 
If the image exists but the user does not have rights to access it, I respond with a 403 error.

Here's a simplified code example...

```js
$img.error(function () {
        alert("Image not known or access denied.");
    })
    .attr("src", "getimg.php?key=horse&user=fred");
```

I'd like to give a different message depending on whether the problem is with the image key, or whether it is that the user does not have access.

Is there some way that I can either access the HTTP error code returned, or the text returned within the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the url to the PHP script directly in the src attribute your javascript is not going to be aware of any errors in fetching the image. One way to solve this is to fire an AJAX request for the image:

```
$.ajax( "getimg.php?key=horse&user=fred" )
 .fail(function(jqXHR) {
    // do something here when the image wasn't loaded
    if(jqXHR.status === 403) {
       // access denied
    } else if(jqXHR.status === 404) {
      // not found
    }
  });
```

The `jqXHR` object contains information like what status code was thrown, what the response from the server was, etc. More information [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Note that I only use the `.fail()` callback here and don't do anything when the image load was successful. It makes little sense to AJAX in an image, you can still just set the src to the right url and that will take care of everything when the image could be loaded. The only reason we're using AJAX here is in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I thought of trying something with AJAX, but then couldn't figure out whether it was possible to assign the response to the image on success. With your suggestion am I making two calls to the server? Maybe it would be cached so not a problem?

Comment: Yes, the request will be fired twice. I'm not entirely certain, but as many image preloaders use a similar construction I do believe this method will allow the image to be cached.

Comment: Initially when I tried this it repeated the request, so I needed to make some changes server-side to ensure the image was cached...
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=86400");
    header("Pragma: cache");
Works great now. Thanks